# Failue to build when running nx serve on react app

Tags: build, npx, react-tsx, nx-monorepo, nx.dev

I am trying to serve my react app called frontend (it has been working previously) and I am not sure what has broken.

If anyone can shed any light on what may be the problem that would be awesome, here is my issue.

When I run "nx serve frontend" I get the error:

**NX   Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'build')**

and all I get out of adding --verbose is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'build')
    at readTargetOptions (/home/demo/project/node_modules/@nx/devkit/src/executors/read-target-options.js:21:61)
    at getBuildOptions (/home/demo/project/node_modules/@nx/webpack/src/executors/dev-server/dev-server.impl.js:77:57)
    at devServerExecutor (/home/demo/project/node_modules/@nx/webpack/src/executors/dev-server/dev-server.impl.js:19:68)
    at devServerExecutor.next (<anonymous>)
    at getLastValueFromAsyncIterableIterator (/home/demo/project/node_modules/nx/src/utils/async-iterator.js:13:27)
    at iteratorToProcessStatusCode (/home/demo/project/node_modules/nx/src/command-line/run/run.js:41:94)
    at /home/demo/project/node_modules/nx/src/command-line/run/run.js:154:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async handleErrors (/home/demo/project/node_modules/nx/src/utils/params.js:9:16)
    at async process.<anonymous> (/home/demo/project/node_modules/nx/bin/run-executor.js:59:28)
```

I only have a nx.json in the root of the project and a separate project.json in the react app folder (front end).

It is really stumping me an any pointers would appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any projects listed in your nx.json, remove them. See github answer for the same issue: https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/20983

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).